# Scrape data for list of URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of URLs which I would like to perform web scraping for each URL in the list.

```python
def soup():
    for url in website_list:
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        print (url)
        for things in sauce:
            soup_maker = BeautifulSoup(things, 'html.parser')
            return soup_maker
```

Trying something like this. Could you help with the next step?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: This is too broad. Please do some work yourself, and return if you encounter a **specific** technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give you an example of using frame simplified_scrapy to download. You need to install simplified_scrapy first. pip install simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
class DemoSpider(Spider):
  name = 'demo-spider'
  start_urls = ['http://example.com'] # Replace with your website_list 

  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    try:
      doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
      print (doc.title)
    except Exception as e:
      print ('extract',e)

SimplifiedMain.startThread(DemoSpider())# start scrapping
```

Comment: Thank you @dabingsou I made it work using BeautifulSoup.
Now I am trying to save the scraped data to a text file but some of the content is getting removed in the text file.
I am using this:
file = open("MDMDataFiles/copy.txt", "w") 
data = soup.get_text()
data
file.write(soup.get_text()) 
file.close()
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Paste the downloaded page data and the data you want to extract from the page data, so that you can have targeted suggestions